# Cannot upload file with FormData on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I can't upload file with FormData to React Native. I am using **react-native-document-picker** and here is my code:

```js
try {
    const pickerResult = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
        presentationStyle: 'fullScreen',
        copyTo: 'documentDirectory',
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf],
        mode: 'import',
    });
    setAccountStatement(pickerResult);
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', {
        uri: pickerResult.fileCopyUri,
        type: pickerResult.type,
        name: pickerResult.name,
        fileName: pickerResult.name,
        size: pickerResult.size,
    });
    console.log(data);
    http
        .post('url', data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
};
```

Here's the example response I get from react-native-document-picker

```
{
    "fileCopyUri": "file:///data/user/0/com.crust/files/497ed9ec-79fb-4bfb-81d1-74907f851c08/receipt_20220929065209.pdf", 
    "name": "receipt_20220929065209.pdf", 
    "size": 36036, 
    "type": "application/pdf", 
    "uri": "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A223934"
}
```

Please how do I go about this? I get

> Error: Request failed with status code 415

from the server and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Fails in Android or iOS or both?

Comment: fails on both Android and ios

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to solve the issue after 2 days of tirelessly trying to figure it out , i managed to have two different solutions to the problem

**1. Using Fetch API**

```
     const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('file', {
        uri: pickerResult.fileCopyUri,
        type: pickerResult.type,
        name: pickerResult.name,
        fileName: pickerResult.name,
        size: pickerResult.size,
      });


       try {
           const res = await fetch(
             'url',
             {
               method: 'POST',
               mode: 'no-cors',
               headers: {
                 Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
               },
               body: fd,
             },
           );
           console.log(res.status, res.statusText);
           if (res.ok) {
             console.log('Success');
           } else {
             console.log(await res.json());
           }
         } catch (error) {
           console.error(error);
         }
```

**2. Downgrading Axios to "^0.24.0"**

after i figured it out using the fetch api ,i was able to do a deeper research and found out that,

> axios has a problem with the FormData() object, from version "^0.25.0"

, so i

> downgraded my axios version to "^0.24.0"

and it worked like a charm including image upload using "FormData()"